# within my app to send and receive text thru android sms api

Tags: android

Can I use android's sms api to have users send and receive messages without leaving my app at all? i.e., as far as the users know, the sms is completely part of my app.

So far my understanding is that I can have a user send an sms from within my app, but the recipient will not get the sms within my app.

Comment: what  *google* tells you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. By using the `SmsManager` you can send the SMS from your own app. You can also set up listeners to intercept received messages and display them to the user. All this has been done by a lot of app developers.

Comment: Could I include images with these sms?

Comment: Yes you can, but then it will become a multimedia message.